# How to read multiple CSV (leaving out specific ones) from a nested directory in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I have a directory called 'all_data', and inside this, I have several other directories based on the date of the data that it contains. These directories are named date_2020_11_01 to date_2020_11_30 and each one of these contain csv files which I intend to read in a single dataframe.

But I don't want to read the data for date_2020_11_15 and date_2020_11_16. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to exclude certain files, but you can specify a range of file names using brackets. Code below would select all files without 11_15 and 11_16:

```
spark.read.csv("date_2020_11_{1[0-4,7-9],[0,2-3][0-9]}.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df= spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load(paths)
```

where paths is a list of all the paths where data is present, worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Simple method is, read all data directory as it is and apply filter condition

`df.filter("dataColumn != 'date_2020_11_15' & 'date_2020_11_16'")`

Else you can use OS module read directory and iterate to that list to eliminate those date directory using condition.

Comment: there is not column named in 'dataColumn' in the original data. So i cant use that field to filter out data.